# Delphi go up a directory using ExtractFilePath

Tags: delphi

I'm using this code:

```
str := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '\Connection.ini';
```

to get the path of an `.ini` file, but I want to go up by 2 directories, so the `.ini` file doesn't sit in the DEBUG folder.

I tried this:

```
str := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '\..\..\Connection.ini';
```

But didn't work...

Comment: `str := ExtractFilePath(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))) + '\Connection.ini';`

Comment: It should work, as listed. But a better approach would be: str:=TPath.Combine(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)),'..\..\Connection.ini'); or str:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))+'..\..\Connection.ini';

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Answer it so I can mark as accepted!

Comment: @HeartWare thanks, why would it be a better approach?

Comment: it seemed you only wanted up once:
`str := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '\..\Connection.ini';`

Comment: @nick: Because you don't assume if the ExtractFilePath ends with a trailing backslash or not...

Comment: @HeartWare: You don't have to assume anything. `ExtractFilePath` has always included a trailing path delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few possibilities to go one directory up. Some of them include:

```
str := ExtractFilePath(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))) + '\Connection.ini';
```

or

```
str := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))) + 'Connection.ini';
```

or

```
str := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '\..\Connection.ini';
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this function:

```
TYPE DirStr = STRING;
TYPE CpuWord = Cardinal;

FUNCTION EXECPATH : DirStr;
  BEGIN
    Result:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))
  END;

FUNCTION XPATH : DirStr;
  VAR
    P   : CpuWord;

  BEGIN
    Result:=EXECPATH;
    {$IFDEF WINDOWS }
      {$IFDEF CPU64BITS }
        P:=POS('\WIN64\',UpperCase(Result));
      {$ELSE }
        P:=POS('\WIN32\',UpperCase(Result));
      {$ENDIF }
      IF P>0 THEN SetLength(Result,P)
    {$ENDIF }
  END;
```

That way, it'll work both when the file *is* within the default directory when compiling from the IDE *and* when run from an installation directory.

Use EXECPATH if you want the *true* directory that the .EXE file resides in, and XPATH is you want the "*logical*" directory (ie. if within \Win32\Debug and the like, step out of this).

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer from Ondrej, I used this method:

```
function GetParentFolder(folder: String; const cLevels: BYTE = 1) : String;
var
    parent: String;
    level: BYTE;
begin
    // Given "C:\Parent\Child\" or "C:\Parent\Child\MyFile.txt", return "C:\Parent\"
    if (cLevels > 0) then
        begin
        parent := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(folder);
        level := 0;
        while (level < cLevels) do
            begin
            parent := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFilePath(parent)));
            Inc(level);
            end;

        Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(parent);
        end
    else
        Result := folder;
end;
```

And use it like this:

```
str := GetParentFolder(ParamStr(0), 2) + 'Connection.ini';
```

The advantage, IMO, is that this works with both a full path or just a directory (without filename). Moreover, you can navigate any number of levels up as required.